# How to only rerender react component when specific state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization, rerender

I have a custom input component like this:

```
<MyComp
   propA={data.someData}
/>
```

say I render this 10 times on my page, how do I stop it re-rendering unless the specific instance has changed?

Currently when I update the first instance, all the other components will make a graphql request (my component is somewhat complicated) because when they do this they update some state and then that state is what you see in `propA` which gets passed back down

I know I can wrap it in `memo` but I'm struggling to see how I say "only re-render if this specific instance changes". I can't do prop comparison because the same data is getting passed down through all the props if that makes sense. I almost need to say "if NOT typing in specific instance, do not call query" not sure how I do that in react though?

is the only way to pull out my state from `data` and set each set individually?

Comment: Why don't you move the graphql request to a higher level to make it once in a parent component and pass the result in child components?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a deep comparison, for example using this library https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect

```
useDeepCompareEffect(
() => {
  // make an HTTP request or whatever with the query and variables
  // optionally return a cleanup function if necessary
},
// query is a string, but variables is an object. With the way Query is used
// in the example above, `variables` will be a new object every render.
// useDeepCompareEffect will do a deep comparison and your callback is only
// run when the variables object actually has changes.
[query, variables],
```

)